# update pandas dataframe column with a sequence for matching rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with 3 columns.

```
Event_occur Boolean
Event_predict Boolean
Incorrect_pred Number default 0
```

Please refer to the screenshot. I am trying to update Incorrect_pred based on certain conditions.

1. Whenever Event_occur is True and Event_predict is False,
   Incorrect_pred should be updated with an increasing number sequence.
   Example, the first occurrence of Event_occur =True and Event_predict
   =False, should update Incorrect_pred with 1, the second occurence with 2 and so on.
2. Whenever the 2 events are both True, then
   Incorrect_pred should be updated with the previous non zero
   number.(refer index row 5 and 9 in the example).
3. Whenever
   Event_occur is False, the update is always 0 which is the default
   value.

If this was sql, I could have used a windows function. Something like:

```
(case
   when Event_occur = 'FALSE' then 0
   else sum(case when Event_occur = Event_predict) then 0 else 1 end)
 over (order by <some column>) end)
```

Is there a way I can do this in pandas?

[expected dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32X55.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try:

```
df['pred'] = np.where(df.Event_occur == False,0,np.where(df.Event_occur != df.Event_predict,1,0)).cumsum()
df['Incorrect_pred']= df.pred.where(df.Event_occur == True).fillna(0)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Event_occur  Event_predict  Incorrect_pred  pred
0        False           True             0.0     0
1         True          False             1.0     1
2         True          False             2.0     2
3        False          False             0.0     2
4         True          False             3.0     3
5         True           True             3.0     3
6         True           True             3.0     3
7         True          False             4.0     4
8        False           True             0.0     4
9         True           True             4.0     4
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks Scott!